# Jython regex subsubgroup name for re.sub

Tags: python, regex, jython

Hi I have the following re which works fine:

```
re.sub("(?P<colon>(, )\s*|^)(?P<field>[A-Za-z]*)", "\\g<colon>`\\g<field>`", fields
```

however I would like to do this (capture the inner group):

```
re.sub("((?P<colon>, )\s*|^)(?P<field>[A-Za-z]*)", "\\g<colon>`\\g<field>`", fields
```

however if I try to reference the group wich is in a group (for instance the group holding only g in this:`r(e(g)e)x`) I get an `unmatched group` error/exception.

so how do I reference nested capture groups or is it not possible with jython (approx python 2.5.1)

**edit**:fixed according to answer from Qtax (A-z => A-Za-z) however my real problem is not solved yet

Answer (score 1):

All these groups capture, some of them are just not named. You should be able to reference any capturing group, altho I don't know python/jython regex specs by heart. Try an expression like:

```
re.sub("(?:(, )\s*|^)([A-Za-z]*)", r"\1`\2`", ...)
```

You cannot use `[A-z]` if you mean `A-Z` and `a-z`, that can be written `[A-Za-z]` or used with some case insensitive flag, eg `(?i)[a-z]`.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on why I can't use [A-z], since for the moment it shows the expected behaviour. I tried with the numbering as you suggested, however that yielded the error, thus I tried named subgroups. I also tired the non capturing part (`?:`) before but that did not help either.

Comment: @ted, `[A-z]` means any character in the ASCII table that is between and including `A` and `z`. This includes more than just the letters, see [any ASCII table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).